# Asp.net image control problem

Tags: asp.net

Hi i have a problem with my image control that is when i upload an image it shows that image but when i update it, its shows old image while updates in data base i think it gets image from cache is there any technique to handle this issue kindly tell me.

```
Image1.ImageUrl = populatedata.ResultSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][12].ToString();
string file_ext = Path.GetFileName(Image1.ImageUrl);
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/EmpImages/" + file_ext;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the image url everytime you get it through some random generated query string.

This way the browser won't cache it.

For instance:

```
int randomNumber = (new Random()).Next(0, 10000);
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/EmpImages/" + file_ext + "?rand=" + randomNumber;
```

But if the problem only happens sporadically and image updates aren't so oftem, you can just press `Ctrl+F5` on the browser and it will refresh all files.

Comment: when i open it in new browser it shows new picture but i want to see new picture in same browser how it would be possible